# addPermission() API method in Package Manager

Tags: android

I am trying to dynamically add permissions to the system in my Android code. [addPermission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#addPermission(android.content.pm.PermissionInfo)) method seems to take a [PermissionInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html) object as a parameter and I tried the following but it throws an "java.lang.SecurityException: Label must be specified in permission" error:

```
    PermissionInfo pi = new PermissionInfo();
    pi.name = myCustomPermission;
    pi.protectionLevel = PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS;
    final PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    packageManager.addPermission(pi);
```

I did add  component in the manifest file too. I couldn't find any examples online. Would be great if you could describe me how to do this or point me to examples.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Fee free to read at [Understanding App Permissions](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions)

Comment: This doesn't explain dynamic permissions added by addPermission().

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
    PermissionInfo pi = new PermissionInfo();
    pi.name = myCustomPermission;
    pi.labelRes = R.string.permission_label;
    pi.protectionLevel = PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS;
    final PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    packageManager.addPermission(pi);
```

(As taught by [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=y11NBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22applications%20can%20also%20add%20new%20permissions%20dynamically%20using%20the%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.addPermission()%22&source=bl&ots=nU_ACVpR2x&sig=ZXYNDYBcFgqwi9uCVfUvUzN58ZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTo_OH9-DRAhWQ0YMKHXv8CKoQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22applications%20can%20also%20add%20new%20permissions%20dynamically%20using%20the%20android.content.pm.PackageManager.addPermission()%22&f=false))

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work because it seems we need additional permissions which require to be signed with the platform key, which isn't mentioned by the above book. What is the reason for requiring these permissions?